# How do I exclude NativeScript documents() folder from iCloud?

Tags: ios, nativescript

I have many files that are downloaded to NativeScript documents() folder and subfolders.
According to apple guidelines I should not upload these files to iCloud.
My question is how do I exclude it in NativeScript?

Comment: iCould sync doesn't happen by default, first of all you will have to enable iCould capability on your application and app id in developer portal, then mark any folder / file specifically for iCould backup. Unless you do so, it won't sync. You don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Are you sure?
From what I read, all application data is automatically backed up to iCloud.
Can you refer me to a document stating that NativeScript documents(); folder is not automatically backed up to iCloud?
I don't want to face rejection from apple for this tiny detail (it happened to me on a native application).

Comment: See here: https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html
It specifically mention that Documents is automatically backed up in iCloud. I have to disable it.

Comment: Okay, there are two different kinds of iCould backups. I was talking about the one that's specific to app, make your files available on multiple devices when your application is installed. You seem asking about the device wide backup option that's enabled by user. What kind of files you add to your documents directory? Do you write a lot of files as soon app is launched?

Comment: Yes, I am downloading files from our own cloud service and I don't want these to be backed up on iCloud as it is forbidden by Apple to upload files that are otherwise accessible by the user.
I asked another question about excluding directory and you gave me this line: NSURL.URLWithString(path).setResourceValueForKeyError(true, NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey);
I did not know it is so simple to access this from NativeScript.